# How to declare the type of a default exported function

Tags: typescript, express

I have several express middlewares in my codebase, which are each in their own file. I want to type them all as `express.Handler` instead of typing every argument itself.

My files look basically like this:

```js
export default function exampleMiddleware (req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.body.helloWorld)
}
```

But `req`, `res` and `next` are all treated as `any`, because TypeScript doesn't know that this function is supposed to be an `express.Handler`. What is the correct way to do this?

I do *not* want to change them to this, because it is so verbose:

```js
import * as express from 'express'

export default function exampleMiddleware (
  req: express.Request, 
  res: express.Response, 
  next: express.NextFunction
): void {
  res.send(req.body.helloWorld)
}
```

I tried:

- `declare function exampleMiddleware: express.Handler`, but it says "Overload signatures must all be exported or non-exported"
- Adding `let exampleMiddleware: express.Handler`, but it says "Merged declaration 'exampleMiddleware' cannot include a default export declaration."

Comment: `import {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express'` might help reduce vebosity.

Comment: Things work much better if you avoid default exports altogether: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html

Answer (score 1):

If I avoid default exports (like @spender commented), then I can indeed use:

```
export const exampleMiddleware: express.Handler = function exampleMiddleware (
  req, 
  res, 
  next
) {
  res.send(req.body.helloWorld)
}
```

Which is good enough for my purposes, I guess.